# Как зациклить функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, qtimer

У меня есть программа:

```
import time


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1110, 671)
        self.la_non = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.la_non.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1091, 71))
        self.la_non.setStyleSheet("font: 48pt \"Molot\";")
        self.la_non.setObjectName("la_non")
        self.label_lime = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_lime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 1071, 491))
        self.label_lime.setStyleSheet("font: 55pt \"Molot\";")
        self.label_lime.setObjectName("label_lime")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.la_non.setText(_translate("Form", "1234"))


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent) 

        self.setupUi(self)

    def time(self):
        import time

        time = str(time.strftime("%X"))
        hour, minute, second = time.split(':')
        self.label_lime.setText(str(23 - int(hour)) + " " + "часов" + " " + str(59 - int(minute)) + " " +"минут" + " " + str(60 - int(second)) + " " + "секунд")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)                        
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

нужно зациклить метод `time()`.

Comment: а зачем вы объявили time, hour minute, second глобальными??

Comment: это остатки прошлой версии

Comment: В приведенном коде нет функции time.

Comment: def time(self):

Comment: def time, import time, time = ... что это за сюр?

Comment: def time - определение функции

Comment: import time- импортирование модуля времени

Comment: time = ... - определение текущего времени

Comment: Что это все означает понятно. У вас ТРИ разные вещи названы одинаково. В этот раз, может, и работает, но если будете так делать, то рано или поздно начнете ловить баги, которые потом замучаетесь искать.

Comment: Да и импортировать time второй раз необязательно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Класс QTimer предоставляет повторяющиеся и одиночные таймеры.

```
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1110, 671)
        self.la_non = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.la_non.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1091, 71))
        self.la_non.setStyleSheet("font: 48pt \"Molot\";")
        self.la_non.setObjectName("la_non")
        self.label_lime = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_lime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 1071, 491))
        self.label_lime.setStyleSheet("font: 55pt \"Molot\";")
        self.label_lime.setObjectName("label_lime")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.la_non.setText(_translate("Form", "1234"))


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent) 

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.time)
        self.timer.start()

    def time(self):
        import time
        time = str(time.strftime("%X"))
        print(time)

        hour, minute, second = time.split(':')
        self.label_lime.setText(str(23 - int(hour)) + " " + "часов" + " " + str(59 - int(minute)) + " " +"минут" + " " + str(60 - int(second)) + " " + "секунд")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)                        
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]